# Install wifi driver without Ethernet

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm a beginner using Linux, and when I installed Ubuntu yesterday, and at first all was working fine, the wifi worked and all was ok. Then today when u started the computer the wifi didn't work, I tried looking for a solution online but all of them involve using an Ethernet cable, which isn't a possibility in my case. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu so I could install all the drivers thinking that if the last time worked this time should, but it didn't, I can boot into windows and there wifi works, and the Bluetooth which is the same module works fine in both OS

Please help me

Comment: Please provide Ubuntu product & release details. It may also help if you're specific as to what ISO you wrote to installation media & thus installed from, as it'll help us know what options are available for your currently *unknown* Ubuntu product & *unknown* release.  Many ISOs have flexibility, others are made before you download the ISO (ie. grab the first, or alternate ISO..)

Comment: Also add the result of this query to your question above `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` and we might be able to get you temporarily online with a modprobe.